# Returning validation error message as JSON

Tags: json, laravel

I want to return a failed validation attempt message in JSON from laravel's validator. But upon failed validation I get an 'invalid JSON response' instead. It is not returning any of the custom messages. What am I doing wrong?

Controller

```
public function uploadArtwork(Request $request) {

$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [

        'artwork-title' => 'required|max:240',
        'artwork-description' => 'max:120|nullable',
        'artwork-medium' => 'max:120|nullable',
        'artwork-software' => 'max:120|nullable',
        'artwork-tags' => 'max:120|nullable',
        'files' => 'required',
        'files.*' =>  'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:5024',
],
    [   
        'artwork-title.required' => 'Error: Please add title',
        'files.required' => 'choose a photo.',
        'files.image' => 'file should be an image.',
        'files.max' => 'Your photo is too large',
        'files.mimes' => 'We only accept :values.',
   ]
);


 if ($validator->fails()) {
        
 return response()->json($validator->errors());
 
 }
```

js

```
 error: function (file, response) {

   // $("#status-message").text(responseText);
   console.log(response);

  }
```

Comment: you are not returning an error response, you are returning a regular 200 response, btw

Answer (score 1):

Actually, above way you didn't send an error response. You are sending a successful response. If you change something like the below will work.

```
if($validator->fails()){
   return response()->json([
      'status'   => 'error',
      'message'  => $validator->getMessageBag()
   ], 400);
}
```

For more info refer: [Return validation error message as JSON - Laravel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061391/return-validation-error-message-as-json-laravel-6)

Comment: How may I get the JSON response and then output as HTML text? I even tried console.log(response); in my JS file but I get nothing in return.

Comment: For error response, validation needs to be failed. What about your validation?